# MSBuild Plugin projects build and copying in csproj

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have an C# app app that is loading plugins, during development phase I want to have them copied to app output directory with their dependencies so I can debug easily. I have a task in the app csproj that takes care of it.

```
<Target Name="CopyPlugins" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PluginProject Include="..\Plugins\Example\Example.csproj" />
        <PluginProject Include="..\Plugins\ExampleWithDependencies\ExampleWithDependencies.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects="@(PluginProject)" Targets="Restore" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(PluginProject)" Targets="Build" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(PluginProject)" Targets="Publish" Properties="PublishDir=$(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

That works like a charm for plugins that are not referencing any libs that needs to be built. For projects tha are having dependencies than need to be built, I'm getting error during executing the `Build` target: `error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\my\project\path\Plugins\Libs\SomeDependencyLib\obj\x64\Debug\net8.0\ref\SomeDependencyLib.dll' could not be found`

To me it looks like the nested referenced projects are not being buit, if I compile such project explicitely, then the app task succeeds.

Any hint how to enforce building project with its dependencies via MSBuild task?

Updates from experimenting:

- it happens only from withing Visual Studio, when running it on commandline with VS MSBuild, it works as expected
- Looks like it tries to build referenced projects but those fail due definitions to generate AssemblyInfo values that are defined in `Directory.Build.props` file that is on solution level

Comment: Your `@(PluginProject)` item collection is a just a collection of paths. It is not "nested referenced projects". Are you adding [`ProjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference)s for each plugin project?

Comment: It's intended to be path collection, it should work as is. I have discovered that this behavoir is having errors only from within Visual Studio, if I use VS version of MSBuild on commandline, it works as expected. Using ProjectReference inside a task will treat it as string variable. To be sure I tested it and yes it beaves as I have described, no change. 
Thx Jonathan

Comment: _"Using ProjectReference inside a task will treat it as string variable"_ is not true. An `ItemGroup` doesn't become a `PropertyGroup` within a target.